# How to change chart type in crystal reports

Tags: c#, .net, crystal-reports-2008

I am using visual studio 2008 and I want to change the Chart type upon activating run time in crystal reports. For example, we have various chart type options in Bar Chart, line Chart, Area, Pie etc.

Appreciate if anyone could tell me the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you can change that on run time. What you can do is create the charts in different sections each and then suppress them and only show the chart based on a parameter or something else.

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim oldChart As CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ReportDefModel.ChartObject
    Dim newChart As CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ReportDefModel.ChartObject
    oldChart = CType(rcd.ReportDefController.ReportObjectController.GetReportObjectsByKind(CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ReportDefModel.CrReportObjectKindEnum.crReportObjectKindChart)(0), CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ReportDefModel.ChartObject)
    newChart = CType(oldChart.Clone(True), CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ReportDefModel.ChartObject)
    newChart.ChartStyle.TextOptions.Title = "My New Chart Title"
    newChart.ChartStyle.TextOptions.DataTitle = "My New Data Title"
    newChart.ChartStyle.TextOptions.GroupTitle = "My New Group Title"
    newChart.ChartStyle.TextOptions.Subtitle = "My New subtitle"
    newChart.ChartStyle.Type = **CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ReportDefModel.CrChartStyleTypeEnum.crChartStyleTypePie**
```